# What is the state of matter-energy inside Black Holes?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, vacuum, stability

Do we know absolutely nothing about what might be the state of matter-energy inside the black hole?

Are there existing theories or research that explore the possibility of a metastable vacuum inside black holes?

Comment: There is a fairly large literature on vacuum decay, and last time I searched for "black hole decay" at ArXiv I got a bundle of papers arguing whether there would be near-horizon decay or not. So the problem is not whether there is theories here, but with which papers to start.

Comment: Resource and published recommendation,?